# Plot variables as slope of line between points

Tags: r

Due to the nature of my specification, the results of my regression coefficients provide the slope (change in yield) between two points; therefore, I would like to plot these coefficients using the slope of a line between these two points with the first point `(0, -0.7620)` as the intercept.  Please note this is a programming question; not a statistics question.

I'm not entirely sure how to implement this in base graphics or ggplot and would appreciate any help.  Here is some sample data.

Sample Data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 29), y = c(-0.762,-0.000434, 0.00158, 0.0000822, -0.00294, 0.00246, -0.000521, -0.00009287, -0.01035) )
```

Output:

```
   x          y
1  0 -7.620e-01
2  5 -4.340e-04
3  8  1.580e-03
4 10  8.220e-05
5 12 -2.940e-03
6 15  2.460e-03
7 20 -5.210e-04
8 25 -9.287e-05
9 29 -1.035e-02
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: does it mean you want nine lines in your graph?

Comment: @MLavoie Yes, there should be 9 lines

Comment: I am not sure if this is right the answer so let try it as a comment first, run ggplot()  +  geom_abline(data=df, aes(intercept = x, slope = y)) + ylim(0, 100) + xlim(0, 100)

Comment: @MLavoie That is not correct.  Please see updated question with example picture

Comment: how do you want the y value calculated. Gor example, using your figure, what is the y-coord for when x=5. Is it `-7.620e-01 + 5* 4.340e-04` or ...

Comment: Something like `ggplot(aes(x, cumsum(y)), data = df) + geom_line() + geom_text(label = df$y, nudge_y = .0002)`? Or do you want MLavoie's above with labels? I'm still not quite sure what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cumsum`, the cumulative sum, to calculate intermediate values

```
  df <- data.frame(x=c(0, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 29),y=cumsum(c(-0.762,-0.000434, 0.00158, 0.0000822, -0.00294, 0.00246, -0.000521, -0.00009287, -0.0103)))
  plot(df$x,df$y)
```

[image]